# Effective way to "wrap" subclass methods

Tags: python

The following code has the desired functionality:

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self, worker):
        self.worker = worker

    def foo(self):
        self.worker.run()

class Worker:
    def run(self):
        print('about to run...')
        self._run()
        print('just ran...')

    def _run(self):
        print('running...')

class SpecialWorker(Worker)
    def _run(self):
        print('running very fast...')
```

The idea is that I have a generic worker class which implements an important `_run` method. However, external processes access `_run` through the `run` method of the `Worker` class which basically just wraps `_run`. The reason I work this way is that subclasses to `Worker` will have the appropriate wrapping no matter how `_run` is defined, but also people developing new subclasses do not need to take care to explicitly include the wrapping code.

My question is if there is a better way to do this that doesn't involve splitting the `run` method out into two  methods, one of which calls the other. What I basically want is a way that the `Worker` `run` method will be wrapped with certain functionality in all subclasses of `Worker`.

Any suggestions other that what I've presented?

Comment: This is a very common pattern. Nothing wrong with it, at least on the generic level which we can see here.

Comment: Anyone making subclasses should at least be calling `super().run()` in their own `run()` implementation, with saves them from having to know about `_run()` in the first place.

Comment: This is the [Template Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

Comment: @zvone The issues I have with it are purely cosmetic and have to do with naming. The disadvantage here is that the name of the method defined in `SpecialWorker`, `_run()`, does not match the name of the method which is called in `MainClass.foo`, `run()`. I would prefer if these two methods had the same name.

Other than that the code I have posted does achieve the desired functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever one function needs to be wrapped by another in Python, decorators come to mind.  Outside of classes they are more straightforward, but they could be used in this situation as well.  I'm not sure the approach is more elegant than your original solution, but here is what a decorator based approach might look like:

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self, worker):
        self.worker = worker

    def foo(self):
        self.worker.run()

class Worker:    
    @staticmethod
    def orchestrate_run(func):
        def wrapped_run(self):
            print('about to run...')
            func(self)
            print('just ran...')
        return wrapped_run
    
class SpecialWorker(Worker):
    @Worker.orchestrate_run
    def run(self):
        print('running very fast...')
```

```
worker = SpecialWorker()
mc = MainClass(worker)
mc.foo()
```

```
about to run...
running very fast...
just ran...
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I'd prefer the person who write the subclass to not have to know to wrap it with anything.